# how to solve disk structure corrupted and unreadable error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am working in asp.net , i got one live issue error. first line of asp.net page  show the error as "disk structure corrupted and unreadable".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the error in first line..

Comment: I'm afraid you have to ask your local hardware dealer.

Comment: yes Soner Gonul, youre right please help

Comment: Error:8 Files has invalid value "��VJ��t�x�i��j�\,V�~ �s�}������". Illegal characters in path. ReportModels         error showing like this........................

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="xxxxxx.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxxx.xxxxx" %> showing error in this line